# String to date conversion android

Tags: java, android, datetime, date-format

I have an android app in which i want to convert my string into date data type.
I get the string via date picker in this format ("12/30/2011").
I want to convert it into string in the same format. This is my code:

```
        Date dateObj = new Date();
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        dateObj = dateFormat.parse("12/30/2011");
        Log.v("",""+dateObj);
```

But i get value in this form:

Wed Dec 28 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2011

Comment: what code print `Wed Dec 28 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2011`?

Comment: My log prints dateObj value as Wed Dec 28 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it help?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
sdf.format(new Date())
```

[Please have a look at this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class DateIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

**Output: 12/28/2011**

In place of

```
Log.v("",""+dateObj);
```

use this

```
 Log.v("",""+sdf.format(new Date()));
```

*You shouldn't print the original date object but the formatted one.*

Comment: sorry! it doesnt change anything

Comment: this is the correct way. If it doesn't change anything, it means you are applying it wrongly.

Comment: thanks....... somewhat the answer. i parsed the string and then formatted it like u said

Answer (score 1):

```
Date dateObj = new Date();
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
dateObj = dateFormat.parse("12/30/2011");
Log.v("", "" + dateFormat.format(dateObj));
```

Try this one. `dateFormat.format()` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking parse and format.

Here:

```
    Date dateObj = new Date();
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String dateAsString = dateFormat.format(dateObj);
    Log.v("",dateAsString);
```

Also, please note that concatenating an object with a String always uses the toString method of the object. In the case of a Date object, toString returns a basic default formating, not related to the SimpleDateFormat you declare above.

Answer (score -1):

```
date : String date
formatpattern : String formatPatten

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatpattern);
Date date = formatter.parse(date);
```