# android convert a string to a date format the convert back to string

Tags: java, android, date

What i'm wanting to do is format the string `08-18 15:00` to read `18-08-12 15:00`. How do I convert it into a date format it and the convert back to a string so i can use to setText to a textview?

Comment: The year portion of your date is missing. It is always 12?

Comment: hi yeah it should say 2012-08-18 15:00 however for some reason it's not saving my edits to my question

Comment: What about using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. You have to use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Here is the link: [String to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655178/735675)

Answer (score 2):

Of course, using SimpleDateFormat would be better solution, but if you insist and if you know coming style... Then you can simply format it yourself, with some codes like this:

```
public static String ConvertDate(String valueToFormat) {
      String value = valueToFormat;
      String day = value.substring(value.indexOf("-") + 1, value.indexOf(" "));
      String month = value.substring(0, value.indexOf("-"));
      String time = value.substring(value.indexOf(" ") + 1, value.lenght());

      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

      // if you want year to appear as only last two items
      year = year % 100;

      value = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + time;
      return value;
}
```